# Source map points always to same line

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack, source-maps, webpack-style-loader

I've just noticed that when I inspect any element in Chrome or Firefox dev tools the attributes assigned to that element always point to **same line**, which is **either the end of the source file** (when I open static index.html) or, if I run my app by `webpack-dev-server`, **beginning of the file**.

[image]

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module:  {
        loaders: [
            {
                test:   /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            },
            {
                test:   /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    loader: ['css-loader?sourceMap', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    loader: ['css-loader?sourceMap']
                })
            },
            {
                test:    /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader:  'babel-loader',
                query:   {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    entry:     [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './app/static/js/app.js'
    ],
    output:    {
        filename: './app/dist/js/bundle.js',
        //publicPath: './', // adding back will break webpack-dev-server!
    },
    watch:     false,
    plugins:   [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('./app/dist/css/main.css'),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    devServer: {
        host:        'localhost',
        //hot: true, // adding back will break webpack-dev-server!
        port:        8080,
        inline:      true,
        stats:       '_errors-only',
        contentBase: './'
    }
};
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "new-admin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "0.44132ff81411f73136a6.hot-update.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
    "bootstrap-loader": "^2.0.0-beta.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "postcss": "^5.2.5",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "webpack-uglify-js-plugin": "^1.1.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "postcss-load-config": "^1.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but the `postcss-loader` has no sourceMap argument. Maybe try something as: `'postcss-loader?sourceMap=inline'`?

Comment: no difference, attributes of `body .menu__element` and `body nav` both keep pointing to `body`